# The out parameter 'recordsReturned' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method ObjectCache

Tags: c#, caching

I'm stuck on trying to work out how to solve the error above, how can i assign the value to recordsReturned which is an output parameter from the database and add it to ObjectCache.

Before the data is cached I can get the value, but I cannot add it to the cache, i have tried out and ref, but with no luck.

Hopefully someone with more experience than me can help with my problem.

I've added my code below:

```
public class RetrieveTravelGuideForSearchResults : IRetrieveTravelGuideForSearchResults
    {
        private readonly string _dbConn;
        public RetrieveTravelGuideForSearchResults()
            {
                _dbConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADO_DBConn"].ConnectionString;
            }

        public IEnumerable<DisplayTravelGuideForSearchResults> DisplayTravelGuideSearchResults(string id,out int recordsReturned)
        {
            string cacheData                = "DisplayTravelGuideSearchResults" + RegexHelpers.RegexRemoveAllInvalidCharactersAndSpace(id.ToLower());
            ObjectCache travelGuideCache    = MemoryCache.Default;
            var objectInCache               = travelGuideCache.Get(cacheData) as IEnumerable<DisplayTravelGuideForSearchResults>;

            //recordsReturned = 0;

            if (objectInCache != null)
            {
                recordsReturned = 0; //How can I get value from output parameter and add it here
                return objectInCache;
            }
            const string spName = "dbo.spFTSTravelGuide";
            //recordsReturned = 0;
            using (var cn = new SqlConnection(_dbConn))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, cn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SearchPhrase", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100));
                    cmd.Parameters["@SearchPhrase"].Value = id;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RecordsReturn", SqlDbType.Int));
                    cmd.Parameters["@RecordsReturn"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


                    var data = new List<DisplayTravelGuideForSearchResults>();
                    try
                    {
                        cn.Open();
                        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                        {
                            if (rdr.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (rdr.Read())
                                {
                                    data.Add(new DisplayTravelGuideForSearchResults
                                    {

                                        Country = (string)rdr["TravelGuideCountry"],
                                        Description = RegexHelpers.RegexRemoveHtmlTags((string)rdr["TravelGuideDescription"])
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15) };
                        travelGuideCache.Add(cacheData, data, policy);
                        recordsReturned = cmd.Parameters["@RecordsReturn"].Value as int? ?? 0;

                        return data;
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the recordsReturned value  in the output parameter to the stored procedure have any relation to the number of records returned in the data reader?

Comment: Hi twrowsell the output parameter did not have any relation to the number of records in the data reader, should have worded my question better :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have got the answer to my problem, should have done

```
recordsReturned = cmd.Parameters["@RecordsReturn"].Value as int? ?? 0;
travelGuideCache.Add("recordsReturned", recordsReturned, policy);
```

and then

```
if (objectInCache != null)
            {
                recordsReturned = travelGuideCache.Get("recordsReturned") as int? ?? 0;
                return objectInCache;
            }
```

This now get the output parameter value and allows me to cache it.